# How to scale (and position etc) to more exact measurements?

Tags: transforms

BH

I need to scale my mesh to a very precise amount to match certain calculations, the number I need to scale it by is about `30621.17235345582` but when I copy that into the scale field, it cuts off many decimal points

Which would be fine for smaller scaling that doesn't need to be so precise, but in this case a few decimal points can be many meters less than the intended amount

Is there a way to scale with all of those decimal points? Perhaps a script?

Comment: You can't get beyond roughly 8 significant digits because of the way Blender does floating point math.

Comment: @MartyFouts not even with a script?

Comment: @MartyFouts is there a way to break up the scale into multiple times (by applying etc)?

Comment: It's a limitation of how floating point works. There's no way to get the level of precision you want using the single precision floating point math used in Blender.

Comment: @marty okay but is there a way to split it it, scale it a little bit, then apply the scale etc and repeat the process?